# Undefined index error, multiple db connections in file

Tags: php, mysql, sql, indexing

I have a php file/script running in powershell which is meant to connect to one db server, select info, connect to another db/server and insert that info.

I was having problems with the connections, but now I have it working, except when I run this script in powershell I get a slew of errors, 5 to be exact (which matches the records in the database currently) about undefined index.

This affects line 51 through 55 which happen to be the end of my code, the `VALUES` section, starting with the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` line. My table in mysql workbench has the exact same column names, index values, etc. that my test table has where I execute this script for testing in workbench. Am I calling those values incorrectly in my insert statement?

```
    <?php

    $servername = "//";
    $username = "//";
    $password = "//";

    $servername2 = "//";
    $username2 = "//";
    $password2 = "//";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
    $conn2 = new mysqli($servername2, $username2, $password2);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";

    // Check connection2
    if ($conn2->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn2->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";

    $data = mysqli_query($conn, " SELECT c.extension
                          ,RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID
                          , sum(Duration) AS Total_Talk_Time_seconds
                          , round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) AS Total_Talk_Time_minutes
                          , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) AS Total_Outbound
                          , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0)) AS Total_Inbound
                          , sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) AS Total_Missed
                          , count(DISTINCT b.NOTABLECALLID) AS Total_Calls
                          , NOW() AS time
                          , curdate() AS date
                      FROM cdrdb.session a
                      LEFT JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b
                           ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
                      LEFT join cdrdb.mxuser c
                           ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
                      WHERE b.ts >= curdate()
                      AND c.extension IN (7295,7306,7218,7247,7330,7000,7358)
                      group by c.extension");


            foreach ($data as $d) {

                    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn2, "Insert into jfi.ambitionphone(Extension, ExtID, Total_Talk_Time_seconds,
                          Total_Talk_Time_minutes,Total_Outbound, Total_Inbound,
                          Missed_Calls, Total_Calls, Time_of_report,Date_of_report  )
                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
                            ON duplicate key update
                            Total_Talk_Time_seconds = values(Total_Talk_Time_seconds),
                            Total_Talk_Time_minutes = values(Total_Talk_Time_minutes),
                            Total_Outbound = values(Total_Outbound),
                            Total_Inbound = values(Total_Inbound),
                            Missed_calls = values(Missed_Calls),
                            Total_Calls = values(Total_Calls),
                            Time_of_report = values(Time_of_report),
                            Date_of_report = values(Date_of_report)");
                            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssiiiiiiss", $d['extension'], $d['RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID'],
                            $d['Total_Talk_Time_seconds'], $d['Total_Talk_Time_minutes'],
                            $d['Total_Outbound'], $d['Total_Inbound'], $d['Total_Missed'], $d['Total_Calls'],
                            $d['time'], $d['date']);

            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

            }

     ?>
```

UPDATE:

This is the mysql query I'm converting to this PHP script, for context:

```
Insert into test.ambition_test(Extension, ExtID, Total_Talk_Time_seconds,
Total_Talk_Time_minutes,Total_Outbound, Total_Inbound, 
Missed_Calls, Total_Calls, Time_of_report,Date_of_report  )  
SELECT 
 c.extension 
,RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID 
, sum(Duration) 
, round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) 
, sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) 
, sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0)) 
, sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) 
-- , count(DISTINCT b.NOTABLECALLID) as Total_Calls
, sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) + sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0))   as total_calls 
, NOW()
, curdate() 
FROM cdrdb.session a
LEFT JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b
 ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
LEFT join cdrdb.mxuser c
 ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
WHERE b.ts >= curdate()
AND c.extension IN (7295,7306,7218,7247,7330,7000,7358)
group by c.extension
ON duplicate key update Total_Talk_Time_seconds 
=values(Total_Talk_Time_seconds), 
Total_Talk_Time_minutes =values(Total_Talk_Time_minutes), 
Total_Outbound = values(Total_Outbound), 
Total_Inbound = values(Total_Inbound), 
Missed_calls = values(Missed_calls), 
Total_Calls = values(Total_Calls), 
Time_of_report = NOW();
```

Comment: Don't you have to fetch the results with a `while()` instead of `foreach()` on the query?

Comment: Pretty sure you are right @Rasclatt because it's not PDO

Comment: so I would do something along the lines of  ``` while($row = mysql_fetch_array) ``` ? Sorry, I don't know the exact syntax I would use

Comment: @rasclatt How exactly would I have to modify that outside of doing a while and create a fetch variable?

Comment: @TomN. `while($d = $data->fetch_assoc())`

Comment: @Rasclatt http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php says that iterator support was added in PHP 5.4.0. If he couldn't use `foreach` he would be getting an "Invalid argument to `foreach`" error.

Comment: It's not related to the PHP error, but you're missing the `VALUES` clause of the `INSERT`.

Comment: And inside the `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, the argument to `VALUES` has to be a column name, not a string.

Comment: @Barmar so I would remove the quotes around my column names? I'm just trying to understand exactly how I need to change my code

Comment: @Barmar good to know! I use PDO exclusively so I was going off recollection from days of old.

Comment: @Barmar I edited and added my original MySQL query that I'm basing this script off of and I think the values clause issue is because my query is inserting and selecting the values. For clarification, I'm having to select the values from a read only db connection/server and inserting into another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't assign aliases to the function calls in the first query. So there's no columns named `Total_Outbound`, `Total_Inbound`, etc. It should be:

```
$data = mysqli_query($conn, " SELECT c.extension
                              ,RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID
                              , sum(Duration) AS Total_Talk_Time_seconds
                              , round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) AS Total_Talk_Time_minutes
                              , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) AS Total_Outbound
                              , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0)) AS Total_Inbound
                              , sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) AS Total_Missed
                              , count(DISTINCT b.NOTABLECALLID) AS Total_Calls
                              , NOW() AS time
                              , curdate() AS date
                          FROM cdrdb.session a
                          LEFT JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b
                               ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
                          LEFT join cdrdb.mxuser c
                               ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
                          WHERE b.ts >= curdate()
                          AND c.extension IN (7295,7306,7218,7247,7330,7000,7358)
                          group by c.extension");
```

Then you also need to fix the syntax of your `INSERT` query. It doesn't specify the values to insert, so how is it supposed to tell if you're creating a duplicate key? And you should use a prepared statement to avoid quoting issues.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn2, "Insert into jfi.ambitionphone(Extension, ExtID, Total_Talk_Time_seconds,
                      Total_Talk_Time_minutes,Total_Outbound, Total_Inbound,
                      Missed_Calls, Total_Calls, Time_of_report,Date_of_report  )
                        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
                        ON duplicate key update 
                        Total_Talk_Time_seconds = values(Total_Talk_Time_seconds), 
                        Total_Talk_Time_minutes = values(Total_Talk_Time_minutes), 
                        Total_Outbound = values(Total_Outbound), 
                        Total_Inbound = values(Total_Inbound), 
                        Missed_calls = values(Missed_Calls), 
                        Total_Calls = values(Total_Calls), 
                        Time_of_report = values(Time_of_report), 
                        Date_of_report = values(Date_of_report)");

foreach ($data as $d) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssiiiiiiss", $d['extension'], $d['RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID'], 
        $d['Total_Talk_Time_seconds'], $d['Total_Talk_Time_minutes'], 
        $d['Total_Outbound'], $d['Total_Inbound'], $d['Total_Missed'], $d['Total_Calls'],
        $d['time'], $d['date']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, and the $stmt block, all of that would be within my foreach loop, correct?

Comment: Actually, you only need to call `prepare` and `bind_param` once, outside the loop.

Comment: Sorry, I"m just slightly confused. I thought the select query had to be done outside the loop to create the $data variable. I've updated my code above, but I'm not sure what to remove from the foreach loop

Comment: That's correct, `SELECT` should be outside the loop. I've updated the answer to show the new `foreach` loop.

Comment: Thank you I modified it and no more errors in powershell! Still no results in my database table, but that could be a different issue, though I would think I might get an error on that

Comment: I can't see any reason why it wouldn't insert anything. Add error checking -- put `or die(mysqli_error($conn2));` after each of the calls on the second DB.

Comment: Leaving the field out of the `INSERT` column list should do that. An `AUTO_INSERT` column shouldn't complain about no default value.

Comment: Thank you that helped. I fixed the ID column in my table to be auto-incremented, now It's saying column 'extension' cannot be null. I'm wondering if I'll have to alter all of my columns?

Comment: Maybe you should be using `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`, then you won't get null extensions.

Comment: It rarely makes sense to use `GROUP BY` on a column coming from a `LEFT JOIN` table, since all the non-matching rows will be grouped together.

Comment: I see what you're saying. The issue too, i think, is that my query for mysql works perfectly within workbench, but converting it into this PHP script is what's giving me the issues

Comment: I don't see any way you can get a null extension. `WHERE c.extension in (...)` ensures that `c.extension` is one of those listed values, and will never be null.

Comment: Ok, Finally got it to finish in powershell and insert, and my table just has 6 rows with 'NULL" in every field except for ID

Comment: I don't know, are you? That means the first 2 columns are strings (`extension` and `ExtID`, then 6 integers (various counts), then 2 more strings (`time` and `date`).

Comment: If you do `var_dump($d)` inside the loop, do you see the columns?

Comment: I'm altering that now. THe data types have changed so it's 4 Ints, a float, 4 ints, date and timestamp. However, that's now not matching my variables in the bind_param section so I think I need to remove the first one for ID

Comment: so I guess those field types aren't doing to work. I can't use f for float or d for date, t for timestamp

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) The possible types are `integer`, `double`, `string`, and `blob`, and you put the first character of the type in the string. But that's not causing your problem, MySQL is pretty flexible about converting types.

Comment: Ok well I changed that around and fixed it my just using i,d, and s correctly so it ran again. I just have to dig and figure out why it's inserting null values, when it's obviously getting the correct row count. Thank you for your help though

Comment: Try putting the `bind_param` call inside the loop. Maybe there's an issue with binding to associative array columns before the array is assigned.

Comment: Yes! That got it. thank you so much. This helps make sense of the whole script a bit more for me